# Fedora 23: how to take screenshot with context menu window opened on the screen

Tags: fedora, eclipse, screenshot

I need to take a screenshot that records my Eclipse IDE menu item status. For example, if I clicked the "Project" menu and there comes a list of menu items. I need to record those menu items.

The problem is when the menu item list window (which works like a context menu window) has the focus, the screenshot function is not working. I tried everything on this [link](https://fedoramagazine.org/take-screenshots-on-fedora/) and nothing works as long as the menu items window is opened. Any mouse click will close the context menu window, so I cannot use mouse either. However if there is no context menu window opened then screenshots works fine.

How can I record the screen with context menu window displayed?

Comment: what desktop you are using?

Comment: the default on fedora 23, I think it's gnome

Comment: for GNOME see the answer provided; alternatively `xfce4-screenshooter` being invoked from command line or from Accessories menu offers an option to take a screenshot after a specified delay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GNOME, or have some GNOME tools installed, you can use `gnome-screenshot` with the `--delay=#` option. The delay is in seconds, and gives you that many seconds to open the "Project" menu so that it is open when the screencap actually happens. I also recommend the `--window` option to keep clutter in the screenshot to a minimum.

Pass the `-f filename` option to `gnome-screenshot` to save the resulting image to a file called `filename`. See `man gnome-screenshot`.

So to summarize, a command like

```
gnome-screenshot  --window --delay=10 -f foo.jpg
```

will work.